# When using logstash to index data from MySQL to ElasticSearch,it shows Java heapspace error

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, logstash

MySQL table has 191000 rows. When I try the below it runs for a while and shows this error:

```
logstash/bin/logstash -f /home/vatsa/logs/conts-out.conf
```

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   Dumping heap to /home/vatsa/logstash/heapdump.hprof
>   Exception flushing buffer at interval! {:error=>"Java heap space", :class=>"Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError", :level=>:warn}
>   Error: Your application used more memory than the safety cap of 1G.
>   Specify -J-Xmx####m to increase it (#### = cap size in MB).
>   Specify -w for full OutOfMemoryError stack trace

I dont understand the error. How to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running Logstash with more memory: `logstash/bin/logstash -J-Xmx2048m -f /home/vatsa/logs/conts-out.conf`

Comment: Same error? Try increasing even more (3072, 4096, etc) as long as you have some more RAM available on your machine.

Comment: i tried it,with the following error: Unrecognised option '-J'
 signal_usage_error at /home/vatsa/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:103
find_option at /home/vatsa/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/option/parsing.rb:62
run at /home/vatsa/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.1-java/lib/logstash/runner.rb:79
call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281 initialize at /home/vatsa/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.22/lib/stud/task.rb:24
No idea what the error is!! how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try enabling query paging. This will limit the number of elements retrieved from MySQL. Corresponding setting are the following:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    ...
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    jdbc_page_size => 100000
    ...
  }
}
```

From Logstash [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-jdbc_paging_enabled) of jdbc_paging_enabled:

> This will cause a sql statement to be broken up into multiple queries. Each query will use limits and offsets to collectively retrieve the full result-set.